# Why am I getting a syntax error at group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created the following query but when I run it I get a syntax error at the GROUP BY clause but when I remove it PostgreSQL gives me the error that I need to add t.bsn to a GROUP BY clause. How can I fix this error?

```
SELECT t.bsn
FROM teachers t, designes d, students s, course c, teaches lg
WHERE c.course_follower = s.class AND t.bsn = lg.bsn AND d.course_code = c.course_code AND d.bsn = t.bsn AND s.class = lg.class 
HAVING t.salary = (2000 + (t.scale * 200) + ((t.scale - 10) * 300) + (100 * (COUNT(d.course_code) * (1.0 + (0.1 * COUNT(s.student_id)))) + (50 * c.amount_of_assignments)))
GROUP BY t.bsn;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` comes before `HAVING`.  But there are other large problems with your query.  You're creating a Cartesian Product of those four tables.  As a rule of thumb, commas should *never* be in the `FROM` clause (a practice that has been deprecated for **25 years** now.).  Use the explicit `JOIN` syntax instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to SQL standards the `HAVING` clause should come **AFTER** `GROUP BY`; yours is before.

Your Code:

```
SELECT 
        t.bsn
FROM 
        teachers t, designes d, students s, course c, teaches lg
WHERE 
        c.course_follower = s.class AND 
        t.bsn = lg.bsn AND 
        d.course_code = c.course_code AND 
        d.bsn = t.bsn AND 
        s.class = lg.class 
HAVING 
        t.salary = (2000 + (t.scale * 200) + ((t.scale - 10) * 300) + (100 * (COUNT(d.course_code) * (1.0 + (0.1 * COUNT(s.student_id)))) + (50 * c.amount_of_assignments)))
GROUP BY
        t.bsn;
```

Expected:

```
SELECT 
        t.bsn
FROM 
        teachers t, designes d, students s, course c, teaches lg
WHERE 
        c.course_follower = s.class AND 
        t.bsn = lg.bsn AND 
        d.course_code = c.course_code AND 
        d.bsn = t.bsn AND 
        s.class = lg.class 
GROUP BY
        t.bsn
HAVING 
        t.salary = (2000 + (t.scale * 200) + ((t.scale - 10) * 300) + (100 * (COUNT(d.course_code) * (1.0 + (0.1 * COUNT(s.student_id)))) + (50 * c.amount_of_assignments)));
```

Generic SQL Example - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

PostgreSQL SQL Example - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-agg.html